# javascript : Event execute multiple time after loading page via ajax.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a page which will be loaded via ajax. On this page i have created a function which will assign some function for the specified keys [I'm using jquery Hot keys].

Here is the function that i use to assign functions

```
function setupKeys() 
{
    $.each(keyMap, function (event, listener_name){
       $(document).bind('keydown', event, listener[listener_name]);
    });
}
```

This will be executed each time when page is loaded.

If l load the page for the first time and press enter key the function will executed. Suppose if i load the page again via ajax with out refersing the browser and press the enter key the function executes two times. And i repeat the same the function will be executes three times.

How can i avoid this? keyMap is an object

```
keyMap = {
'Ctrl+s':'save_data',
'return':'test_return',
'tab':'test_return'
};
```

listener = new Array();

Please help.

[sorry for the poor English]

Krish.

Answer (score 1):

Why not unbind the event before binding? No probs nothing is bound, prevents double event registration.

```
function setupKeys() 
{
    $.each(keyMap, function (event, listener_name){
       $(document).unbind('keydown', listener[listener_name]);
       $(document).bind('keydown', event, listener[listener_name]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you spender. I tried as you suggested but still the events event triggers multiple times. But if i ensure that 'setupKeys' is executed only for one time, something like marc suggested , than event triggers only one time even if i reload the page via ajax. But My issued is that i have to use this function in multiple pages.

Comment: I made some changes to the code instead of assigning event to the document i tried assigning it to form then tried `console.log($("#mainForm").data('events'));` it only shows something like this in firebug `keydown Object {}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether setupKeys has been executed. Just add a variable

```
var isSetupKeysCalled = false;
```

that will be set to `false` inside of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unbind the event before you bind it to ensure that events are not tirggered multiple times on the page.

```
$.each(keyMap, function (event, listener_name){
       $(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', event, listener[listener_name]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resolve the issue with unbind method. So i have modified the function as marc suggested. And i think its working now.

Thank you marc

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved !

As i was using jquery Hot keys following syntax should be used to unbind the event

```
 $.each(keyMap, function (event, listener_name){ 
            $(document).unbind('keydown', event, listener[listener_name]);
            $(document).bind('keydown', event, listener[listener_name]);
        });
```